# How to override typescript generic through as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to override typescript generic variable through `as` prop?

```js
type Component<Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = React.FC<JSX.IntrinsicElements[Tag] & { as?: Tag }>;

const Test: Component<'div'>;

<Test />; // ok
<Test as="div" />; // ok
<Test as="input" onChange={e => e.target.value} />; // "as" prop is not working, so "onChange" has wrong definition
<Test as="a" href="url" />; // "as" prop is not working, so "href" has no definition
```